# Attempting to Get User ID of Profile Being Viewed

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

The PHP script I am developing needs to pull a field value from the database based upon the profile being viewed at that time.  Currently I have developed this script and it is functioning for me with the exception of one item.  The problem is that the value it is displaying is based upon the user’s profile who is logged in rather than the profile being viewed.  For example, let’s say that there is a field associated with each profile titled `profile_key`.  The user who is logged in has the following value:

`profile_key=123`

When this user views their own profile, they see the following:

`profile_key=123`

Now, let’s continue this example with a second user.  The second user (who is not logged in) has a key value of the following:

`profile_key=789`

Currently, when the logged in user (first user) visits the non-logged in user (second user), the logged in user sees the following displayed on the non-logged in user’s profile:

`profile_key=123`

The key value which should be display when the logged in user visits the non-logged in user’s profile is the value set for that user’s profile:

`profile_key=789`

This site is based in Joomla, and here is a snippet from the script which shows the query to obtain the profile key value:

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
// Get User ID
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->id;
// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query = 'SELECT cb_profilekey FROM #__comprofiler WHERE user_id = ' . $id.'';
```

As you can see, the query is pulling the value based upon the id of the user viewing the page rather than the is of the user page being viewed.  This is where I need some adjustment I believe.  Thank you for your time in this request, any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

this will always gives you the logged in user as object. you need to get the id of the profile, say from request like this.

```
$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Nagarjun, I have tried changing:


`$user = JFactory::getUser();`
`$id = $user->id;`

to the following:

`$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id', 0);`
It does not seem to be pulling the data with this adjustment.  I have researched the `getApplication` call and this appears to be for Joomla 1.5.  I am using Joomla 2.5, could this be the reason this is not working?  Thanks, -Presto

Comment: It is J2.5 call. it just gets request parameter with name "id". may be you are using different name for id. for example index.php?profile_id=10 here profile_id is the request parameter

Comment: The site is using search engine friendly URLs, so I cannot view the request parameter from the profile link from the browser address.  Is there another way for me to determine this value to test?

Comment: Turn off the sef urls for a minute and take a look at the url to get the name or else read the code to get the name.